# Entity Framework BeginTransaction with Isolation level but no working

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, concurrency, isolation, pessimistic-locking

I'm building database by using mysql connector with **EF6**.
Way to handling concurrency updates happens.

1. **Client A** updates row
2. **Client B** come in updates same row
3. **Client B** need to wait **Client A** commit his updates.
   Codes:

   ```
        using (myEntities db = new myEntities ())
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Open();
            try
            {
                using (var scope = db .Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable))
                {
                    {  
                        var test = db.customer_table.Where(x => x.id == 38).FirstOrDefault();
                        test.bank_holder_name = "CLIENT A";
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        scope.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
   ```

While debugging, I purposely pause when Client A doing this SaveChanges() step.
But Client B can finish his updates without any wait.
Anyone here is experiencing this issue?

P/S: I did a lot reading and trial about Entity Framework concurrency issue, like;
a) Optimistic locking with row_version (Not working perfectly if the timestamp not unique enough to catch concurrency)
b) Transaction Scope (Still the same as result above)

Anyone here have idea to stop concurrency in Entity Framework? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Nothing wrong at the EF layer here.

Comment: @ David Browne - Microsoft Thanks for reply, client A & B instance were executed in local and hosting. Will these 2 instance using the same transaction pool? (The session should stored in database side right? )

Comment: I know less than nothing about MySql, but that's the correct code for EF.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft By default, with this code fo EF, Client B should have waited Client A finish his commit right?

Comment: So long as they are connecting to the same database, that's what I would expect.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft Yup, both are connecting same database. Is this the only way to create pessimistic locking in EF?

Comment: No.  You can always create your DbContext with an alread-open DbConnection, and manage transactions through ADO.NET or raw SQL commands.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft Do you have any related link for details? Once again, thanks for your reply!!